# How to convert png8 in GraphicsMagick

Tags: graphicsmagick

I want to convert an input 8-bit PNG image to 8 bit.

I have tried using GraphicsMagick. But I don't know how to convert png8 in GraphicsMagick.

When I use the command as such:

`gm convert source.png  png8:output.png`

it return the message

`gm convert: Invalid background palette index (output.png).`

My version is GraphicsMagick 1.3.20 2014-08-16 Q8 .

Answer (score 6):

Try using the "-colors 254" option, e.g.,

```
gm convert source.png -colors 254 png8:output.png
```

The "png8:" color reduction is somewhat quick-and-dirty and doesn't do nearly as good a job as the slower `-colors` option, with either GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick.